# Add Classes to LI in ASP.NET RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a `RadioButtonList` that is being rendered as an Unordered list. My issue is I am adding a class to the `ListItem` and it is creating a `span` in which the class is being placed. Is there a way I can have the class placed on the `LI` tag instead? How can I go about it?

```
var cblAttributes = new RadioButtonList();
cblAttributes.ID = controlId;
cblAttributes.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.UnorderedList;

var pvaValueItem = new ListItem(Server.HtmlEncode(frame.Name), frame.FrameId.ToString());
pvaValueItem.Attributes.Add("class", "frame-item");
cblAttributes.Items.Add(pvaValueItem);
```

Output is below:

```
<li>
    <span class="frame-item">
    <input id="INPUTID" type="radio" name="INPUTNAME" value="1">
    <label for="INPUTID">TEXT</label>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you want to apply this class for all list items in the list?

Comment: if anything you could give the `ul` an id and select it in css like `#ulID li { }`. Not really an answer to your question but perhaps a viable workaround.

Comment: @OneHalfTrackMindMan Yes the class would be applied to all. @Bazzz it would be a simple workaround but I am now curious as to how it can be done if it can.

Comment: @brenjt: couldn't you add the class to the RadioButtonList's [CssClass-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) then? Btw, it's an duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070960/set-a-css-class-on-an-asp-net-radiobuttonlist-listitem

Comment: then create new css class like ul.frame-items li { frame-item class definition here } and apply frame-items class on the RadioButtonList via the CssClass property

Comment: @Tim Schmelter It's actually not a duplicate. His question is slightly different.

Comment: @brenjt: yes, sorry, i've seen it myself a few seconds after i've commented. It's only similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new css class like `ul.frame-items li { frame-item class definition here }` and apply frame-items class on the RadioButtonList via the CssClass property

Comment: Great work around. Simple and I had already added this to my css. I want to know out of curiosity if what I asked above can be accomplished.

Comment: I'm not sure but suppose that this can be achieved by implementing own RadioButtonList class inherited from the existing one or with control adapter for the RadioButtonList control.

Comment: Very true. I just found this http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/73982#9854