# Get Value of Radio button group

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to get the value of two radio button groups using the jQuery syntax as given below. When the code below is run I get the value selected from the first radio button group twice instead of getting the value of each individual group.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Thanks for any help :)

```
<a href='#' id='check_var'>Check values</a><br/><br/>
<script>
  $('a#check_var').click(function() {
    alert($("input:radio['name=r']:checked").val()+ ' ' +
          $("input:radio['name=s']:checked").val());
  });
</script>
Group 1<br/>
<input type="radio"  name="r" value="radio1"/> radio1
<input type="radio"  name="r" value="radio2"/> radio2
<br/><br/>
Group 2<br/>
<input type="radio"  name="s" value="radio3"/> radio3
<input type="radio"  name="s" value="radio4"/> radio4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value of a selected radio button using its name in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986120/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-radio-button-using-its-name-in-jquery)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Your quotes only need to surround the value part of the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), `[attr='val']`, like this:

```
$('a#check_var').click(function() {
  alert($("input:radio[name='r']:checked").val()+ ' '+
        $("input:radio[name='s']:checked").val());
});​
```

[You can see the working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c857P/).