# how do I select a parameter a Javascript selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there (I'm a complete JS newbie so please no bullying)
I'm trying to pass formID inside my score variable but I don't think I'm getting my selector right, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Edit: Sorry everyone, I'm getting tired. My issue: I cannot properly select the value of my score var.

JS

```
function addScore(formId) {
var show_id = $('#show_id-'+formId).val();  
var user_id = $('#user_id-'+formId).val();
var score = $('input[value="tvshowrating' + formID +'"]').val();
```

HTML

```
    <form id="40">
        <div class="your-score">
            <div class="">Your Score</div> <div id="flash"></div>
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="1" title="1"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="2" title="2"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="3" title="3"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="4" title="4"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="5" title="5"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="6" title="6"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="7" title="7"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="8" title="8"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="9" title="9"  />
             <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="tvshowrating40" value="10" title="10"  />
             <input type="hidden" id="show_id-40" value="40" /> 
             <input type="hidden" id="user_id-40" value="2" />
             <span id="hover-test" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
             <input id="submitscore" type="submit" value="Submit scores!" onclick="addScore(40);" />  
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Provide code that clearly explains your problem. You've shown us a snippet of JS that doesn't even have a closing function brace.

Comment: Instead of "value=", did you mean to use "name="? As well as use the ":checked" selector to get the chosen input?

Comment: @Ian I think that would be it.

Comment: _"I'm a complete JS newbie so please no bullying"_ - If we can't bully the newbies who _can_ we bully?

Comment: I don't know, go get the html newbies, they're an easier target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the checked value:

```
$('input[name="tvshowrating' + formID +'"]:checked').val()
```

---

Here is another question that answers your problem:
[Get Value of Radio button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464075/get-value-of-radio-button-group)
or
[How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: Finally...somehow who read the question and understands... +1

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting `<input>`s by *value*.

You probably want `input[name=...`.

Comment: The names dont need to be different, just use the ":checked" selector to find which radio button is selected