# Cannot send real value from radio via jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm try to pass the from value (radio button) via ajax. The value sent but wrong. I have 4 radios but the form keeps sending the first value (==1). Could you guys please give me some suggestions. Why it happening?

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">   
<li><label for="1"><input type="radio" name="vote" id="1" class="choice" value="1">&nbsp;Choice 1</label></li>  
<li><label for="2"><input type="radio" name="vote" id="2" class="choice" value="2">&nbsp;Choice 2</label></li>
<li><label for="3"><input type="radio" name="vote" id="3" class="choice" value="3">&nbsp;Choice 3</label></li>
<li><label for="4"><input type="radio" name="vote" id="4" class="choice" value="4">&nbsp;Choice 4</label></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>        
        <div id="vote_loading" style="display:none">loading...</div>
        <div id="vote_result"></div><button class="btn btn-small btn-success" type="button" onClick = "voting()"><i class="icon icon-thumbs-up icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Vote</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    //voting
    function voting(){
         var choice = $('.choice').val();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "inc/vote_chk.php",
             data: {choice:choice}
             }).done(function(result){
             $("#vote_loading").slideUp("slow");
             $("#vote_result").html(result).slideDown("slow");
         });
    }
    </script>
```

By the way I'm using bootstrap. But it's no matter with the code.

Regards,

Comment: jsfiddle? (without the ajax call)

Comment: This will help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464075/get-value-of-radio-button-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you using a class that returns multiple values, its only returning one of them.  To get the selected:

change

```
var choice = $('.choice').val();
```

to

```
var choice = $('.choice:checked').val();
```

I initially thought it was :selected to get the selected radio, but thats for select options.  Combined other answers to not confuse people.  :checked is used for radio buttons.

It should be noted, that it is technically faster to reference by the class rather than by a property of an element though if that matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var choice = $('input[name=vote]:checked').val();
```

Comment: ahhh.  Nice call.  I haven't used a radio button in a while.  :checked is the proper pseudo selector thingy, not :selected.  For radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value of the *class* when you should be retrieving the value of the *input*. That's because many elements can share a class (even non-radio buttons could have class `choice`) but only one element can have the same name.

```
var choice = $('input[name="vote"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
$('input[name=vote]').val()
```