# $.post, radio button value, jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have trouble to pass radio button value by using $.post
can anyone help me find out the problems?

i got  Undefined index:gender

```
<?php
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];    
    if (!$gender) {
        echo $gender;
    }    
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get(){
        $('#error').hide();

        $.post(
            'signup.php', 
            { gender:signup.gender.value },
            function(output){
                $('#error').html(output).fadeIn(100);
            }
        )       
    }
</script>

<form name="signup">
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/> Male<br/>
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> Female
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="get();" />
</form>

<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I also liked this code `if (!$gender) {echo $gender;}` :)

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986120/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-radio-button-using-its-name-in-jquery

Comment: i got  Undefined index:gender

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this line:

```
{ gender: signup.gender.value }
```

To this:

```
{ gender: $('.radio').val() }
```

Of if you wish to keep it as vanilla javascript, you need to explicitly use the `forms` collection:

```
{ gender: document.forms['signup'].gender.value }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery serialize for forms:

```
//Form data:
var aData = $('#formID').serializeArray();
//Create param string:
var sSend = $.param(aData);
//Call ajax:
$.post('signup.php', sSend, function(sData){
   ...
});
```

or for the value:

```
$('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
```

and in your php better:

```
$gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
{ gender: $('.radio [name="gender"]').val() }
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the answer

```
$('input:radio[name=gender]:checked').val()
```

thanks for everyone's help!