# iCheck library: value of selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uYtJ4/).

I'm a novice at Javascript and having trouble following the documentation at the [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) page. I've followed the answer to what appears to be a very relevant StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986120/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-radio-button-using-its-name-in-jquery?rq=1) but cannot get an alert to pop up displaying the value I've selected. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

HTML

```
<p>Are you sure you want to have your details removed from our marketing list?</p>
<div id="unsubscribe_radio">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="iCheck" value="yes">
            <label>Yes</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="iCheck" value="no">
            <label>No</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').iCheck({
     radioClass: 'iradio_flat-orange'
  });
  $("input:radio[name=iCheck]").click(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();
     alert("You clicked " + value);
  });
 });
```

Comment: A plugin which prevents the basic events over plain html elements is a lousy plugin. and should not be used

Comment: I started a project with someone who added this plugin to our code. It is a nightmare to deal with for anything more than a basic website. We're using it in an ASP Core MVC project, and it was constantly rewriting some of our DataBound check/radio controls in ways that prevented page functionality from working as expected.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You must use iCheck like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="iCheck"]').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
        alert("You clicked " + this.value);
    });
    $('input').iCheck({
        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-orange'
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uYtJ4/2/)

[**Documentation**](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/#options)

Comment: Thank you, I see the importance now of 'ifClicked'. The iCheck plugin produces a really neat visual solution, the documentation however assumes a certain level of JS that I'm not at, just yet.

Comment: No problem :) There's a lot of documentation on their website so if you find another error with iCheck you'll most likely find a solution there

Comment: The demo does not seem to work anymore. Seeing `iCheck is not a function` error in the console.

Comment: @Anton Awesome and useful

Answer (score 14):

Just another hacky way to get checked value with jQuery selectors:

```
$(".checked input[name=name-of-original-input]").val();
```

But AFAIK default class for checked values could be changed in configuration.

BTW, I think that iCheck isn't a good choice if it creates such issues with very simple functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I found the other answers to be useful.  However, they are dependent on iCheck's 'ifClicked'.  You may not want the value to pop up every time a new radio button is selected, but instead only when a user hits a specific button calling for the alert and corresponding value.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonClass', function(event) {
  return alert($('.radioClass:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful if you don't want to depend on 'ifClicked'

Answer (score 6):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/yhmu97qh/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-orange'
    });

    $('input').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert("You clicked " + value);
    });
});
```

Comment: The demo does not seem to work anymore. Seeing `iCheck is not a function` error in the console.

Comment: @TotZam iCheck cdn url is not working. I've updated the link http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/yhmu97qh/

Answer (score 1):

this works for me... try it

HTML: `<input type="checkbox" id=checkbox" name="checkbox" />`

jQuery: `$( "#checkbox" ).prop("checked");`

Answer (score 0):

For radio buttons and current version of iCheck:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="my-radio" class="flat-green my-radio" value="true"> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="my-radio" class="flat-red my-radio" value="false"> No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var isChecked = $("input[name=my-radio]:checked").val();
```

It will return undefined if no option is selected, true or false if selected.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
$(".radio .checked input[type=radio]").val()
```