# Get textarea by name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to get field data by ID I will user: `var contentText = $("#contentText").val();`

How do I get field data by field name?

i.e.: `<textarea name="contentText"></textarea>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value of a selected radio button using its name in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986120/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-radio-button-using-its-name-in-jquery)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with attribute selector:

```
 $("textarea[name='contentText']")
```

You can read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/