# How to obtain the value of a text area in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to obtain the value of a specific text area on a form, in a separate javascript file.

I have tried code specified in this stackoverflow link:
[Get textarea by name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117905/get-textarea-by-name-attribute)

however I still obtained null, as the output.

my code is here as follows:

```
 <td>
  <textarea name="key_input" rows="4" cols="50">
    testData
  </textarea>
 </td>
```

and in my js:

```
var key_Data = document.getElementById("key_input").value;
```

this is another way I have tried to obtain the key_input data, but I am still unsuccessful.

Any help would be much appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: getElementById will get an object by "id", not by "name", so no element will be found in your code.

Comment: give id to textarea as `id="key_input"`

Comment: If you wondered why the code from the linked SO question did not work for you, that question was about using the jQuery library (which extends javascript). If you're not using that library, that style of code will not work on your page.

Comment: @Cat I thought the same, but then it's odd that the OP has tagged jQuery in this question. You'd assume in that case they were using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for an Id that doesn't exist, change name to id.

```
id="key_input"
```

And also, just creating the var doesn't show it.

```js
var key_Data = document.getElementById("key_input").value;
console.log(key_Data);
```

```html
<td>
  <textarea id="key_input" rows="4" cols="50">
    testData
  </textarea>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`document.querySelector('[name="key_input"]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[name="key_input"]').value);
```

```html
<td>
  <textarea name="key_input" rows="4" cols="50">
    testData
  </textarea>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an specific `id` attribute to your `textarea` element and use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
const textareaElem = document.querySelector('#key_input');

console.log(textareaElem.value)
```

```html
<textarea id="key_input" name="key_input" rows="4" cols="50">
    testData
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use jquery to do it simply**

```js
console.log($('#key_input').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <textarea name="key_input" rows="4" cols="50" id="key_input">
    testData
  </textarea>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

include the attribute "id" on your text area element

```
<td>
  <textarea name="key_input" id="key_input" rows="4" cols="50">
    testData
  </textarea>
 </td>
```

and your js

`var key_Data = document.getElementById("key_input").value;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(){
   alert(document.getElementsByName("key_input")[0].value)
  }
```

```html
<textarea name="key_input" rows="4" cols="50">
    testData
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="get data" />
```

you can use the above code for `textarea` value get by it's name