# Load URL on radio button select using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using this HTML and Javascript snippet to reload a page when somebody changes the dropdown...

```
  <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

   var orderby = jQuery('#dropdown');
        var str;
        orderby.change(function(){
        str = jQuery(this).val();
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com?variable="+str;
    });
```

Now I am trying to change this so that it works for a radio button instead, my HTML looks like...

```
<input type="radio" id="1" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" id="2" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" id="3" value="3"> 3
```

These are three seperate items so I haven't been able to work out how to modify my js snippet to be compatible, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="1" class="myradio" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="2" class="myradio" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="3" class="myradio" value="3"> 3
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myradio:not(:checked)').on('change', function() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com?variable=" + this.value;
    });
});
```

**Concept Verification**

```js
    $(function() {
        $('.myradio:not(:checked)').on('change', function() {
            alert( this.value );
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="1" class="myradio" value="1"> 1
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" id="2" class="myradio" value="2"> 2
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" id="3" class="myradio" value="3"> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#r1, #r2, #r3").change(function () { 
        str = $(this).val();
        window.location = "http://www.example.com?variable=" + str;
    })
});`

<input type="radio" id="r1" value="1"> 1</input>
<input type="radio" id="r2" value="2"> 2</input>
<input type="radio" id="r3" value="3"> 3</input>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your radios are missing the name attribute, to know the radio button group's name.
After you put the name try something like this

```
jQuery("input:radio[name=GroupName]").click(function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com?variable="+value;
});
```

If you want cross-browser compatibility (But uses more DOM):

```
jQuery("input:radio[name=GroupName]").click(function() {
    var value = jQuery('input:radio[name=theme]:checked').val();
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com?variable="+value;
});
```

Check this question for more: [In jQuery, how do I select an element by its name attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986120/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-radio-button-using-its-name)

Also, before posting a question, you should really research first, because most questions are already answered, all you need is to adapt.