# How to Get A RadioList Value with Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php, radiobuttonlist

I have this:

```
<?php
$list = [];
$list = [1 => 'Aumento' , 0 => 'Disminución'];

echo $form->field($modi, 'aumento')->radioList($list)->label("<b>Seleccione acción a realizar</b>");

?>
```

And I need to get the value of the vector "$list" with a function in javascript, I have:

```
$('#modificaciones-aumento').change(function(){
 var valor = $('#modificaciones-aumento').val();
 alert(valor);
});
```

But it is not working, I've tried using the function "prop.("checked")" as well, but it did not work either.

Comment: could you provide html generated by php ?

Comment: Your radio buttons don't have `id` values. `#modificaciones-aumento` is the `id` of your `div` -> `<div id="modificaciones-aumento">`. Try `#modificaciones-aumento:radio` -> `$('#modificaciones-aumento:radio').change(function(){` (this was based off the html code in your comment that was deleted)

Comment: <div id="modificaciones-aumento"><label><input type="radio" name="Modificaciones[aumento]" value="1"> Aumento</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="Modificaciones[aumento]" value="0"> Disminución</label></div>

Comment: You need to select all radio inputs, like $("input:radio[name=theme]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986120/in-jquery-how-do-i-select-an-element-by-its-name-attribute

Comment: not working Sean nor Aston :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio buttons don't have `id` values. `#modificaciones-aumento` is the `id` of your `div`

```
<div id="modificaciones-aumento">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Modificaciones[aumento]" value="1"> Aumento
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="Modificaciones[aumento]" value="0"> Disminución
    </label>
</div>
```

Try `#modificaciones-aumento :radio` for your selector, and `$(this)` in your function

```
$('#modificaciones-aumento :radio').change(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    alert(valor);
});
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d6mfuv0c/